# Rename multiple files to remove common suffix from filenames

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I have a directory (Linux user) with a number of files which contain an added [!] to the end of each file name so that each file reads out as:

- foo something [!].zip
- bar something [!].zip
- helloworld [!].zip
- etc.

What is the quickest way to batch rename these to remove the ending [!] character combination from these file names?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `rename` tool like this

```
rename 's/\ \[\!\]//' *.zip
```

I recommend that you first add the `-n` switch, which causes `rename` to just show what it will do, but not rename any files.

```
rename -n 's/\ \[\!\]//' *.zip
```

Note that this will only remove the first occurence of `[!]` in the filename, only if it is preceded by a space, and regardless of whether it is at the end of the filename or not.

---

basic syntax of `rename`:

```
rename 's/from/to/' filenames
```

will replace `from` with `to` in all filenames.

here is a detailed explanation: https://www.computerhope.com/unix/rename.htm

---

note there are two `rename` commands: one from the util-linux package and one from the perl package. the command i refer to above is the perl variant. the perl variant is much more popular and useful. usually when people talk about `rename` they mean the perl variant.

in debian (and therefore ubuntu) `rename` is the perl variant by default. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22577767/get-the-perl-rename-utility-instead-of-the-built-in-rename

in arch linux `rename` is the util-linux variant while `perl-rename` is the perl variant. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=85128

here is how you can see what version you are using:

```
$ rename --version
rename from util-linux 2.30.1
$ perl-rename --version
perl-rename 1.9
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way might be to use the Krusader file manager and the Multi Rename tool.

This will allow you to rename multiple files, even recursing down the directory structure.